# MySQL WHERE clause not working with strings

Tags: mysql

I have one table with some email addresses. The address is of course a string, which I've set up on table creation as VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL.

Now, when I use:

```
SELECT * FROM emails;
```

It works fine, if I also select using ID's, it works fine

```
SELECT * FROM emails WHERE id = 1;
```

But if I try to find a particular email

```
SELECT * FROM emails WHERE address = 'email@host.com'
```

It simply doesn't work. It returns no rows matching this, but there *is* a row matching, because it appears on the `SELECT * FROM emails` query.

What can be happening here? Why the WHERE clause is not working?

**EDIT**: The data came from the following import

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/users/user/dev/mysql/emails.txt'
INTO TABLE emails
FIELDS terminated by ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(address)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the row containing this email address has nothing else in that column? spaces, odd character codes etc etc

Comment: Apparently not. I thought on the white spaces, because of that I used `UPDATE emails SET address = TRIM(address)`, but everything continued the same.

Comment: Then try a LIKE to see if there is anything un seeable in there

Comment: With LIKE it works. This data was import from a CSV file. The CSV was just a TXT list, with one e-mail address per line. Perhaps on the import something happened. Is there someway to clean this up?

Comment: I added the import code to the question

Comment: You may need to CLEAN the input file. Try looking at it with an editor that shows you the HEX to see what is actually hiding in there

Comment: I've found the problem. It is the line ending. The file has `\r\n` line endings. This always mess everything up. I fixed the import, by changing `\n` to `\r\n` and everything worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There may be leading or trailing characters in the field.  Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM emails WHERE address LIKE '%email@host.com%'
```